# divide xaml page in different parts

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

i want to implement [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-archive/flex/tourdeflex/web/#docIndex=0;illustIndex=0;sampleId=70030)

(this application is made in flex)type of application using silverlight, how can i do this?
 basically i want is to divide xaml page in 3 parts.., on tree view selection change right parts of page should change dynamically.

Comment: Question is not very clear. Can you provide more info?

Comment: @Mamta Dalal. as shown in given link on tree selection change event  i can load different swf files on a single page..is there any way in silverlight with that i can load multiple xaml files on same page.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish the loading of multiple xaml files by having multiple navigation frames on a page.

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific if you want to get answers that fit your needs.

One way to divide the page is using a [dockpanel](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-DockPanel-in-Silverlight-2.aspx) and you get the behaviour that you describe implementing the TreeView `SelectedItemChanged` event.

Hope hepls!

Comment: as shown in given link on tree selection change event  i can load different swf files on a single page..is there any way in silverlight with that i can load multiple xaml files on same page.?

Comment: @user594979: In that case, have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791270/wpf-custom-control-question/4791332#4791332)

Answer (score 0):

[How to make items in a DockPanel expand to fit all available space in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983732/how-to-make-items-in-a-stackpanel-expand-to-fit-all-available-space-in-wpf)